# Laravel - Trying to get property 'is_approved' of non-object

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project I have this code

Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $currentstatus = AppraisalGoal::select('is_approved')->where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->first();


    $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->get();

    $incompleteCount = $goals->filter(function($item) {
          return ($item->is_approved == 0 || $item->is_approved == 2);
      })->count();       
    return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index')->with(['goals' => $goals, 'incompleteCount' => $incompleteCount])->with('currentstatus', $currentstatus);
}
```

View

```
@foreach($goals as $key => $goal)

@if(in_array($goal->is_approved, [0, 2]))
   <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{ route('appraisal.appraisal_goals.edit', ['id'=>$goal->id]) }}">
     Edit
   </a>
@endif
```

@endforeach

```
    <div class="row no-print">
        <div class="col-12">
         @if ($incompleteCount)
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href ="{{ route('post.publish.all')}}" class="btn btn-primary float-left"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> Publish</a>               
         @endif                  
        </div>       
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is that when the page is loaded Edit and Publish buttons should only be visible when is_approved is 0 or 2.

Instead of seeing this I got this error:

> Trying to get property 'is_approved' of non-object

How do I resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anywhere passing `$goal` to your view. Perhaps you meant `$goals` ?

Comment: @user8555937 - Sorry I forgot to add @foreach($goals as $key => $goal). I have updated the code. Thanks

Comment: are you getting this error on the blade or controller

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your query is not returning any result.

```
$goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->get();
```

You can put an extra check to avoid this error

```
if(count($goals)){
      $incompleteCount = $goals->filter(function($item) {
      return ($item->is_approved == 0 || $item->is_approved == 2);
  })->count();       

}
else {
  $incompleteCount = 0;
}
 return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.index')->with(['goals' => 
 $goals, 'incompleteCount' => $incompleteCount])->with('currentstatus', $currentstatus);
```

Comment: When I changed the code to 
        if(count($goals)){
          $incompleteCount = $goals->filter(function($item) {
              return ($item->is_approved == 0 || $item->is_approved == 2);
          })->count();           
        }     I got this error   Undefined variable: incompleteCount

Comment: You can return zero from the else

Comment: Its still showing the error:  Trying to get property 'is_approved' of non-object

Comment: When I did     $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->get();

dd($goals);   I got  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2336 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: @mikefolu yess, you are getting zero results from your query